# MS Access color query in iif condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to write a query for the requirement below:

[FMV] is a field with numerical value. If value inside [FMV] is less than 14, display the values in the range in GREEN, if the value is greater that 28, display this range values in RED and if in between 28 and 14, AMBER. Also, all the result [FMV] field should come in one field as [FMV] itself with required colors as per condition.

```
SELECT IIF([FMV] > '28', "RED") AND IIF([FMV] BETWEEN '28' AND '14', "AMBER") AND IIF([FMV] < '14', "GREEN")
FROM Qry_pre_FPI_IMV;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the IIF functions.

```
select 
    iif([FMV] > 28,"RED",IIF([FMV] between 28 and 14,"AMBER",IIF([FMV] < 14,"GREEN",""))) Light
FROM Qry_pre_FPI_IMV;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Switch` to do this.

```
SELECT 
Switch(
FMV > 28, "RED"
,FMV >=14 and <=28, "AMBER"
, FMV < 14,"GREEN"
, true,0) Light
FROM Qry_pre_FPI_IMV
```

Comment: I tried your query but when I use the query and create a report, the field comes as 'RED" instead of Red color. I want the values background color to be RED if it meets the condition and so on... now it comes as text ;RED'

Comment: I already have FMV field derived from a query with values in it. All I want is to add background color to the same field based on the range of values in it.

Comment: I already have FMV field derived from a query with values in it. All I want is to add background color to the same field based on the range of values in it. Example: in [FMV], if values are 14, 23, 77, 86, 47 and 94, I want to Display [FMV] exactly as it is but with background colour changed as per the value.